# Compare multiple columns in different data frames R

Tags: r, compare

I have three data frames:

```
dat1 <-  data.frame( "ID" = c("1","2","3","4","5"), Value = c("32", "54", "67", "81", "12"))
dat2 <-  data.frame( "ID" = c("1","2","3","4","5"), Value = c("50", "90", "21", "45", "34"))
dat3 <-  data.frame( "ID" = c("1","2","3","4","5"), Value = c("2", "67", "87", "32", "15"))
```

I would like to compare the column "Value" in the three different data frames. Comparing these, I would like to find out which of them has (in total) the lowest values. For example, dat3 has the lowest values of the three data frames. I didn't get the `compare` function to work. Any thoughts?

Comment: Do you mean which dataframe has the "lowest sum of the values of the Value column"?

Comment: No, not the sum. Like, more, just in total. My real data frame has a column with CV (coefficient of variation) and I would like to know with of my three datasets has "in total" the lowest CV. @Limey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the dataframes in a list, you can `sum` the `Value` column from each and get the index of minimum value with `which.min`.

```
list_df <- list(dat1, dat2, dat3)
which.min(sapply(list_df, function(x) sum(as.numeric(x$Value))))
#[1] 3
```

Answer (score 1):

A base R option

```
which.min(
  colSums(`class<-`(
    sapply(
      list(dat1, dat2, dat3),
      `[[`, "Value"
    ), "numeric"
  ))
)
# [1] 3
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
mget(ls(pattern = '^dat\\d+$')) %>%
     map_dbl(~ .x %>%
                   pull(Value) %>%
                   as.numeric %>%
                   sum) %>% 
    which.min
#dat3 
#   3
```